# How to convert int to json in java

Tags: java, json, int, gson

How can I convert an int to a JSON in java. 
A simple Example:

```
int number = 5; 
Gson gson = new Gson();
String numbersJson = gson.toJson(number);
return number;
```

but this is not working :( because i got 5 as returned value.
I want the json format: `{"number": 5}` as value

Answer (score 8):

If you want a key-value, then either wrap to an Object or a Map:

```
Map<String, Integer> number = new HashMap<>();
number.put("number", 5);
String numbersJson = gson.toJson(number);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just number `5` in json will be `5`. What you need is an object with property `number` that has value of `5`

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("number", 5);
String jsonAsString = json.toString(); // If you want it as string

System.out.println(jsonAsString); // prints {"number":5}
```